# What makes the app crash when launched on my phone?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to figure out how progress bars work so i made a simple app where you have a plus and minus button which change the progress of the progress Bar. No errors in Android studio, but it crashes when launched on my phone (Honor 5X)

```
package net.gamepickle.rcap_new;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int progressStatus = 50;
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.happiness_progress);


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}

public void run(){
    Button plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.happiness_plus);
    Button minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.happiness_minus);







    plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(progressStatus!=100){
                progressStatus += 1;
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
            }
        }
    });

    minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(progressStatus!=0){
                progressStatus -= 1;
                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Answer (score 0):

Please add your stack trace.

It seems that you are calling

```
 ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.happiness_progress);
```

on the class level.
You need to split it. 
Declare: ProgressBar progressBar; 
and on the onCreate function:

```
 @Override 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.happiness_progress); 
  }
```